# Error while opening xmfa generated by progressiveMauve

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, java, mauve

I used commandline progressiveMauve to align two genome .gbk files. The alignment was successful. But when I try to visualize the final .xmfa file with Mauve, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Similarity index is too large.
at org.gel.mauve.histogram.ZoomHistogram.allocateIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.histogram.ZoomHistogram.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.SimilarityIndex.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.XmfaViewerModel.init(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.XmfaViewerModel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.ModelBuilder.buildModel(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.gui.FrameLoader.loadFile(Unknown Source)
at org.gel.mauve.gui.FrameLoader.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I solve this?
Is there another way to visualize the xmfa file.
My aim is to visualize an inversion in one of the genomes.